# How get permalink for the current category or tag?

Tags: categories, permalinks, tags

There was a problem in which it was necessary to get permalink of the category/tag viewed. I have not found standard functions, everything other authors offered was only for categories.

I resoved the problem this way:

```
$url = get_term_link(
    $GLOBALS['wp_query']->queried_object->term_id,
    $GLOBALS['wp_query']->queried_object->taxonomy
);
```

Do you have more interesting solution?

Answer (score 1):

[`get_queried_object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) will give you the current term object being viewed. You can pass that directly to `get_term_link` as the first argument.

```
$url = get_term_link( get_queried_object() );
```